# Swift IOS Reading JSON from url

Tags: ios, json, swift

On the below method, I can get the place value but not the location value. how can I get the location?
Thank you in advance!!

```
func searchDB(looking: String){
    var urlString:String = "URLGOESHERE?q=\(looking)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } 
        else {
            //processing data
            if let arr = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [AnyObject] {
                for currPlace in arr {
                    println(currPlace["name"])
                    println(currPlace["location"])
                }
            }
            else {
                errorOccurred = true
            }
        }//eo potential data
    })
    task.resume()
    }//eom
```

This is the **result output** I am getting:

```
 Optional(Buddha-Bar)    
 Optional(nil)
```

**JSON sample:**
   sample data:
            {
                      "formatted_address": "8-12 Rue Boissy d'Anglas, 75008 Paris, France",
                "geometry": {
                "location":       {
                "lat": 48.868194,
                "lng": 2.321596
                }
                },
                "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
                "id": "560dd225114fd10997f75ee777bad84bcb40c529",
                "name": "Buddha-Bar",
                "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true,
                "weekday_text": []
                },
                "photos": [
                {
                "height": 848,
                "html_attributions": [],
                "photo_reference": "CnRnAAAAifUh9MiqwAgQYdwEp-EnS4e_nPQN_mPYIqdI49UKun_CZKxgtUh_ZqT8QBEqBuel9seoZvyyIVvA5-TlweEqO9_2tORg_cmTi_Cy5L_PAthdZd1_Krqbf7oJNy81RWD3brA8fzeIKJfQTMgo-AT19RIQAg5kKSqeoeedm69uhUWKvBoULDJ1-PoSgv4Lsg5y1rjU_pHm_Ng",
                "width": 1919
                }
                ],
                "place_id": "ChIJRS81ac1v5kcRRUqQBmTTJJU",
                "price_level": 3,
                "rating": 3.7,
                "reference": "CmReAAAAjJskNN69nw3gBVtqLpsX11Psr-QvK6cHPLhF-oDXAbYq7dwLn65b1svUJOLVnRgAbg4K3w7qCj9_hkXvx20q4YNR2714ZQQw89GyFGCtXAxonRh09_uvgK97DewsYRyUEhAczR_GzOvU0mmG1OZr0X3kGhQeJ1Vr3RSnI6VXyzh83W_LIcUK_g",
                "types": [
                "bar",
                "restaurant",
                "food",
                "establishment"
                ]
            },

**Json data without spaces**

sample data:
            {
                "formatted_address": "8-12 Rue Boissy d'Anglas, 75008 Paris, France",
                "geometry": {
                "location": {
                "lat": 48.868194,
                "lng": 2.321596
                }
                },
                "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
                "id": "560dd225114fd10997f75ee777bad84bcb40c529",
                "name": "Buddha-Bar",
                "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true,
                "weekday_text": []
                },
                "photos": [
                {
                "height": 848,
                "html_attributions": [],
                "photo_reference": "CnRnAAAAifUh9MiqwAgQYdwEp-EnS4e_nPQN_mPYIqdI49UKun_CZKxgtUh_ZqT8QBEqBuel9seoZvyyIVvA5-TlweEqO9_2tORg_cmTi_Cy5L_PAthdZd1_Krqbf7oJNy81RWD3brA8fzeIKJfQTMgo-AT19RIQAg5kKSqeoeedm69uhUWKvBoULDJ1-PoSgv4Lsg5y1rjU_pHm_Ng",
                "width": 1919
                }
                ],
                "place_id": "ChIJRS81ac1v5kcRRUqQBmTTJJU",
                "price_level": 3,
                "rating": 3.7,
                "reference": "CmReAAAAjJskNN69nw3gBVtqLpsX11Psr-QvK6cHPLhF-oDXAbYq7dwLn65b1svUJOLVnRgAbg4K3w7qCj9_hkXvx20q4YNR2714ZQQw89GyFGCtXAxonRh09_uvgK97DewsYRyUEhAczR_GzOvU0mmG1OZr0X3kGhQeJ1Vr3RSnI6VXyzh83W_LIcUK_g",
                "types": [
                "bar",
                "restaurant",
                "food",
                "establishment"
                ]
            },

Comment: You need to look closely at the JSON, the sample provided seems incorrect/incomplete.

Comment: yeah sorry i removed the extra fields. json data updated on question above @zaph

Comment: Still missing is the outermost enclosing syntactic element, either "[]" meaning the other most element is an array or "{}" meaning it is a dictionary. I'm tending to believe it is a dictionary in which the "sample data:" is part of the print statement and not part of the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some frustration and game of thrones. the messy solution was the one below.
an alternative may be api like 
https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON

```
 func searchDB(looking: String){

    var errorOccurred:Bool = false

    var urlString:String = "URLGOESHERE?q=\(looking)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
            errorOccurred = true
        } else {
//                println(response) //response from post

            //processing data
            let jsonObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
            if let statusesArray = jsonObject as? NSArray{

                println("********* LEVEL 1 *******")
                println(statusesArray[0])

                if let aStatus = statusesArray[0] as? NSDictionary{
                    println("********* LEVEL 2 *******")
                    println(aStatus)

                    if let geometry = aStatus["geometry"] as? NSDictionary{

                        println("********* LEVEL 3 *******")
                        println(geometry)

                        if let currLocation = geometry["location"] as? NSDictionary{
                            println("********* LEVEL 4 *******")
                            println(currLocation)
                            println(currLocation["lat"])
                            println(currLocation["lng"])

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                errorOccurred = true
            }
        }//eo potential data
    })
    task.resume()

    }//eom
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a little formatting to the pertinent part of the data:

```
sample data: {
    "formatted_address": "8-12 Rue Boissy d'Anglas, 75008 Paris, France",
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 48.868194,
            "lng": 2.321596
        }
    },
    "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
    "id": "560dd225114fd10997f75ee777bad84bcb40c529",
    "name": "Buddha-Bar",
```

It is unclear what "sample data:" means as it is not quoted, it may be something added by the print statement (my guess) in which case it is not needed to access the components.

The name would be addresses as:

> ["name"]

The location is in lat/lon so there will be two accesses:

> ["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
>   ["geometry"]["location"]["lon"]

In the above the applicable language syntax must be applied, in Swift there will be some pain.

See [json.org](http://json.org) for information on JSON.

Comment: when attempting **currPlace["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]** i received the error **Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'String'** @zaph

Comment: You chose Swift, you have to deal with the syntax. ;-)

Comment: Swift makes handling JSON very difficult, a lot of devs go with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).  Swift 2.0 handles this better. Note that the code I presented works as-is in Objective-C, simple.